# Template is not loading

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I have an WPF template but it does not show up when starting the application. No errors in WPF and none anywhere. Just no using of the template. How to figure out what the problem is?

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MoveThumb.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ResizeDecorator.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="RotateDecorator.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- ContentControl style to move, resize and rotate items -->
<Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Control Name="RotateDecorator"
                 Template="{StaticResource RotateDecoratorTemplate}"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
                     Cursor="SizeAll"/>
                    <Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator"
                 Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="RotateDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
<!-- RotateDecorator Template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RotateDecoratorTemplate" TargetType="Control">
    <Grid>
        <my:RotateThumb Margin="-18,-18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <my:RotateThumb Margin="0,-18,-18,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
            </my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
        </my:RotateThumb>
        <my:RotateThumb Margin="0,0,-18,-18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
            </my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
        </my:RotateThumb>
        <my:RotateThumb Margin="-18,0,0,-18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
            </my:RotateThumb.RenderTransform>
        </my:RotateThumb>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: The question is "How to" fix template problems. In the sample above, yes `DesignerItemStyle` is not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to **REORDER the dictioneries & the template** and see if it works,

its all about the **ORDER**, because the last dictionary always **overrides** his previous  Dictionaries (templates) sometimes even if you don't target the same UIElement !

Comment: If found the solution when merging all XAML stuff into one single Dictionary file. The problem seems to be the order of loading templates and style. FIRST it is needed to load template and after the style. Perhaps you want to update your answer. Thanks for your help.